# Google spreadsheet script use array

Tags: javascript, google-sheets, spreadsheet

I made this function in google script

```
function gemOMVG(values) {
  var sum = "";

  for (var i = 0; i < values.length; i++) { 
  sum = sum+values[i];
  }

 return sum;
}
```

I have a range of three horizontal cells with values 'o' 'v' 'g'. My script returns o,v,g seperated by komma's. I would like to have these values in an array so i can perform if statements.

can anyone help me out with this?

Comment: The variable `values` will have a double array, like `[['o'], ['v'], ['g']]`. This is how all multi-cell ranges pass to custom functions. Also, it is unclear what you mean by having them "in an array" (they are already in an array), and what this has to do with performing if statements.

Comment: Thanks, I figured it out (answer below)

Answer (score 0):

I figured it out!

```
function gemOMVG(values) {
  var sum = 0;

  for (var i = 0; i < values[0].length; i++) { 
  //sum += "-"+values[0][i]; 
    if(values[0][i] == 'o'){sum+= 4.5;} 
    else if (values[0][i] == 'm'){sum+= 5;}
    else if (values[0][i] == 'v'){sum+= 6.2;}
    else if(values[0][i] == 'g'){sum+= 8.5;}
  }

  var gem = sum/values[0].length;

  var array = [4.5, 5, 6.2, 8.5];

 function closest(arr, closestTo){

    var closest = Math.max.apply(null, arr); //Get the highest number in arr in case it match nothing.

    for(var i = 0; i < arr.length; i++){ //Loop the array
        if(arr[i] >= closestTo && arr[i] < closest) closest = arr[i]; //Check if it's higher than your number, but lower than your closest value
    }

    return closest; // return the value
}

var roundgem = closest(array, gem);
  if(roundgem == 4.5){return "o";}
  else if(roundgem == 5){return "m";} 
  else if(roundgem == 6.2){return "v";} 
  else if(roundgem == 8.5){return "g";}
}
```